# Clear Input Field Except for Submit Button

Tags: jquery, forms

I have some jQuery setup to automatically clear default values from input forms. However, in Chrome, it is also applying to the submit button. So whenever a user clicks submit, the button loses its value and shrinks.

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery.fn.cleardefault = function() {
return this.focus(function() {
    if( this.value == this.defaultValue ) {
        this.value = "";
    }
}).blur(function() {
    if( !this.value.length ) {
        this.value = this.defaultValue;
    }
});
};
jQuery("input, textarea").cleardefault();
});
```

Here is the CodePen with a working example - as you can see, its only an issue in Chrome:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hoJFB/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To just exclude the submit button you could do

```
jQuery('input:not([type="submit"]), textarea').cleardefault();
```